# Ajax security: how to be sure that data sent back to the server is generated by my code?

Tags: ajax, web-services, security

I apologize in advance if this question sounds naive to you.
The problem is this: I have this function and I want the callback function to send the "response" back to my server via Ajax.

```
function FbInviteFriends()
    {
    FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Hi! Join me on XXXXXXX'
    },
    //My callback function
    function(response){
                 //Send response to my server
    }
```

Is there a way to check that the response I'm going to receive server-side is actually the same I got when the callback function is called and that the response hasn't been modified on the client-side by the user?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure in your case, but I think that if you don't want users to modify the code, you should do it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways, but all of them fall on the same principle - you can never know for sure, so treat it with a grain of salt and validate.

That said, one way to put at least one usage constraint may look like this:

- Page accessed: Generate a token GUID. Render it at the client.
- Store in the user session the moment it was created/used, together with user profile.
- Client appends the token to all Ajax posts.
- Token is validated at the server; must match SessionID, user profile (if any), and maximum usage timeout.

If it fails validation, abort the operation.